# Why did Will say sorry after asking the question?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, about-a-boy

When Marcus's mother attempted to commit suicide in *About A Boy* and was sent to a hospital, Will and Suzie were there. The nurse was asking them about whether the boy has a place to stay that night, and Will asked Suzie a question. Here's the line:

> Will: So...my place or yours?....Sorry...

Why did he say sorry after asking that question? And after that, did Marcus stay at his own place or Suzie's place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The doctor asks if *Marcus* could stay with them and *Will* jokingly asks *Suzie* *"my place or yours?"*. Now that's a line you'd rather ask a date you're going to hook up with and *Will* says that exactly as a joke to *Suzie*, playing with that meaning, who afterall *was* his date before the tragic events unfolded. But soon enough, and with the help of *Suzie*'s confused or even disapproving look, he realizes that this was quite an inappropriate situation for such a joke, so he apologizes immediately afterwards. It's just supposed to be an awkward situation where *Will* makes an insensitive fool of himself.

And after that, he drops *Suzie*, her daughter and *Marcus* off his car and leaves them, so it's pretty likely that *Marcus* stayed at *Suzie*'s that night. It's unlikely for *Suzie* to leave him alone at his own place after such an event, especially since the doctor asked if he could stay with them.